# Como aproximar a visão de sua localização, e fazê-la acompanhar durante um trajeto?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, gps, span

por favor, sou novo na área e estou criando um aplicativo que contará a distância, a velocidade, calorias gastas e o tempo pelo usuário durante uma corrida/caminhada.

o simulador está achando a localização, porém a tela não acompanha a caminhada, além de a visão de cima (comumente chamado de "span"), ficar extremamente longe por padrão, e preciso que ela já inicie aproximada.

Podem me ajudar? Segue abaixo as partes que julgo importante para melhor entendimento de minha dúvida:

Muito obrigado a todos!

// Definindo a precisão da localização

```
    self.gerenciadorGPS.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    segundos = 0.0
    distancia = 0.0
    locations.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.atualizaSegundo(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    startLocationUpdates()
```

//Botão que localiza a localização atual
@IBAction func localizar(_ sender: UIButton) {

```
    // Verificando a autorização de status

    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse && CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways) {

        self.gerenciadorGPS.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    self.mapa.showsUserLocation = true
    self.gerenciadorGPS.delegate = self
    self.gerenciadorGPS.startUpdatingLocation()

var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
        var _locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        _locationManager.activityType = .fitness

        // Movement threshold for new events
        _locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0
        return _locationManager

        let localizacao = _locationManager
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.04, 0.04)
        let regiao = MKCoordinateRegionMake(_locationManager as! CLLocationCoordinate2D, span)            
    }()
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tente realizar o teste em um device, creio que com o simulador você não irá conseguir realizar esses testes.

Você não precisa criar um Timer para poder atualizar a localização, o método "didUpdateLocations" já faz isso automaticamente isso para você.

Answer (score 0):

Para aproximar o mapa da localização, altera o span, como você mesmo falou... Quanto menor o valor do span, mais próxima fica a área visualizada.

Para "acompanhar" o deslocamento, sugiro que na função locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) você centralize a localização no mapa. Assim, sempre que a localização mudar, o usuário vai ser centralizado novamente.

Para centralizar, você pode usar:

let currentSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(defaultSpan, defaultSpan)
let region : MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(desiredLocation.coordinate, currentSpan)
map.setRegion(region, animated: true)